# meaning of the phrase "sit off by oneself"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> If social anxiety nodes are closely connected, you will feel fearful not only of eating in public, but also of speaking in front of your co-workers at that meeting. If fear of eating in public **sits off by itself** and is relatively distant from any other symptoms of the disorder, then you’ll be less incapacitated overall.

Does that mean when the fear disappears...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author has constructed a kind of *psychological model* using "nodes" to talk about how one social anxiety (like eating in public) can be linked to another social anxiety (like speaking in front of coworkers), like [nodes in a network.](https://techterms.com/definition/node).  If the nodes are *closely linked* then the fear may be common to both situations. Otherwise the person may be fearful in one situation but not in the other.

Because it's a model, it's a *metaphor* for the actual relationship between social anxieties; however, I don't have enough information to judge whether it's an accurate metaphor.